# Scrolling Phonegap iOS after input

Tags: javascript, iphone, html, ios, cordova

When a user inputs text on my Phonegap application then returned upon completion, the entire page is scrolled further than it should be.

I am looking for a workaround to ensure that, once unfocused, the page returns to it's normal position.

See image that illustrates issue:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/nAvPj.png

I am using iScroll 4.0 but it is not active on this page.

How can this problem be rectified?

Comment: this is happening because the page is being centered on the input box selected. If the page stayed as it was, you wouldn't be able to see what you were typing, and that would get annoying.

Comment: I understand that. However I am looking for a workaround to ensure that, once unfocused, the page returns to it's normal position.

Comment: did you give something like this a shot? http://jsfiddle.net/f25cb/

Comment: Thanks for your fiddle but if the user doesn't input or presses "done" or "go" from the keyboard instead of pressing the submit button that won't work. Found a solution though - posting below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way forward was to set a Javascript event to take it back to the top of the page (or wherever) once focus has been lost on the input box. This uses the `onblur` method (I guess the opposite of `onfocus`?) and really simply states that once focus is lost, the page snaps back to the top.

Here's the working sample:

```
<input name="foo" id="foo" class="foo" onblur="window.scrollTo(0,0);" type="text" />
```

...with, of course, `onblur="window.scrollTo(0,0);"` being the operative code to return to the top of the page.